# How to find find the next space after N characters in an R character vector?

Tags: r, string, loops, vector, char

I have a few large character vectors of varying lengths that I need to break into smaller lengths for processing within spacyr. I'm currently using substr() within lapply() to split into a list where each list item is 500K characters long.

However, I would like to instead split on the next space after about 500K characters so as to avoid chopping a word in half. Not sure how to amend what I've come up with thus far. My current code sort of like so:

```
#Pretend 'text' is my list of words
chars = c(letters, " ", ".")
text<-paste0(sample(chars, 3000000, replace=TRUE), collapse="")

#split to list of smaller vectors
text_segments<-laply(seq(1,nchar(text),500000), function(i) substr(text, i, i+499999))

#do something with each
for(i in unique(text_segments)){
parsedtxt <- spacy_parse(i)
...
}
```

Each fake word in the above example is 3 letters long, but in my real files the words vary in length.

Any suggestions about approaching the space problem would be greatly appreciated. Code speed is not a concern, but I do appreciate efficiency suggestions nonetheless.

Comment: Please add a sample of your data and a sample of what you want the output to look like so that this problem is reproducible... right now, no one can run it in their own session so it's very difficult to help you. Thanks :)

Comment: I have just added a pretend sample to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get inspiration from the code below and adapt it to your dataset.
First I will make up some data.

```
set.seed(1)    # Make the results reproducible
y1 <- paste(sample(c(letters, " "), 1e3, TRUE), collapse = "")
y2 <- paste(sample(c(letters, " "), 1e3, TRUE), collapse = "")
str_list <- list(y1, y2)
```

Now, the function `fun` does the job. It uses `gregexpr` to get the locations of the spaces and then returns everything from the beginnig of the input string to the first space found.

```
fun <- function(x, threshold){
    blanks <- gregexpr(" +", x)[[1]]
    substr(x, 1, blanks[which(blanks > threshold)[1]] - 1)
}

thresh <- 100

sub <- lapply(str_list, fun, thresh)
lapply(sub, nchar)
#[[1]]
#[1] 103
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 154
```